# Unable to get paid status in a configuration using Firebase and Stripe

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement subscription payments with React, Firebase and Stripe configuration.
And we are rewriting [this repository](https://github.com/stripe-samples/firebase-subscription-payments) created by Stripe engineers to React.

Below is the repository where I rewrote it to React.
[Stripe-Firebase-React](https://github.com/Ema38/Stripe-Firebase-React)
The above repository can do the following

- Sign in
- Sign out
- Payment

However, since we do not get the status as paid, we cannot tell the user that the payment has been made.
How do I get my paid status?

---

The main codes are as follows.

```js
const STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY =
  "pk_test_51ISANPL0xj88kG6SYhHBAq0vvMumxhKL5qtk2O6gwRzMCjZ7mb9BLwGx8fvSwQdNKCVCWlW1DwavpiIcl54E8Qbq00wBeOmIF9";
const taxRates = ["txr_1ISW2nL0xj88kG6S0HUKfuKd"];
const prices = {};
let priceId = "";

const Products = ({ user }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    // get products
    db.collection("products")
      .where("active", "==", true)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          const priceSnap = await doc.ref
            .collection("prices")
            .where("active", "==", true)
            .orderBy("unit_amount")
            .get();
          const productData = doc.data();

          priceSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            priceId = doc.id;
            const priceData = doc.data();
            prices[priceId] = priceData;
            const content = document.createTextNode(
              `${new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
                style: "currency",
                currency: priceData.currency,
              }).format((priceData.unit_amount / 100).toFixed(2))} per ${
                priceData.interval
              }`
            );
            setProduct({
              name: productData.name,
              price: content.data,
            });
          });
        });
      });

    // get subscriptions user
    db.collection("customers")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("subscriptions")
      .where("status", "in", ["trialing", "active"])
      .onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          setActive(false);
          return;
        }
        setActive(true);
        const subscription = snapshot.docs[0].data();
        const priceData = (await subscription.price.get()).data();
        console.log(priceData);
      });
  }, [active, user]);

  const cancell = async () => {
    const functionRef = func.httpsCallable(
      "ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink"
    );
    const { data } = await functionRef({ returnUrl: window.location.origin });
    window.location.assign(data.url);
  };

  const subscribe = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const selectedPrice = {
      price: priceId,
      dynamic_tax_rates: taxRates,
      quantity: 1,
    };
    const docRef = await db
      .collection("customers")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("checkout_sessions")
      .add({
        allow_promotion_codes: true,
        line_items: [selectedPrice],
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
        metadata: {
          key: "value",
        },
      });
    docRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
      const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
      if (error) alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
      if (sessionId) {
        const stripePromise = loadStripe(STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
        const stripe = await stripePromise;
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {active ? (
        <div>
          <h2>You are subscribed.</h2>
          <button onClick={cancell}>Cancell</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>Products</h2>
          <p>Test card numbers: 4242 4242 4242 4242</p>
          <dl>
            <dt>{product ? product.name : ""}</dt>
            <dd>{product ? product.price : ""}</dd>
          </dl>
          <button onClick={subscribe}>Subscribe</button>
        </div>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Signout</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

```
db.collection("customers")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("subscriptions")
      .where("status", "in", ["trialing", "active"])
      .onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {
...
```

Of the main code, the code to get the paid users is the part above.
I think the "subscriptions" collection is created after the payment is made, and the "subscriptions" collection is set to the paid status.
However, when I looked at my Firestore, the "subscriptions" collection was not created.
[image]
However, the permission error was not shown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you supposed to be calling Stripe's API and then populating the values into Firebase?

If you want to get the payment status for a `PaymentIntent`, retrieve the `PaymentIntent` object and check the `status` field. These are the possible status according to https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents:

`requires_payment_method`, `requires_confirmation`, `requires_action`, `processing`, `succeeded`, `canceled`

I see that you're also using Checkout. You may want to consider setting up webhook to listen to events related to your payment process, such as completion of Checkout, or successful payment.